# Verification of correctness of method - solving system of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, solution-verification, systems-of-equations

The task is to solve the following system:

$x+y= z$

$x^2+y^2= z^2$

$x^3+y^3=z^3$

My question is: is it allowed to take square of both sides in the first equation and then use the second equation? In that case  we get: $2xy = z^2 - z$ and so on. There is another way to solve the system, which does not involve squaring both sides and that method is clear to me. I just want to know if squaring is allowed or not. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure you can square an equation.

Comment: But by squaring you should get $2xy = z^2- z^2 = 0$ instead.

Comment: Oh I see now, thank you! I made a mistake above...

Comment: @DietrichBurde Do we need any conditions for domain here (squaring both sides with assumption they are nonnegative? Or we have equality, so they are of the same sign and in the end we just check if results are really solutions?

Answer (score 1):

$$x^3+y^3-z^3+3xyz=(x+y-z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy+xz+yz),$$ which gives $$xyz=0.$$
Can you end it now?

I got
$$\{(0,t,t),(t,0,t)|t\in\mathbb R\}$$

Comment: unbelievable factorization

Answer (score 1):

Hint: mistake in your analysis :

$2xy = z^2 - z$ is wrong.

should be $2xy = z^2 - z^2.$

Answer (score 0):

$x+y= z$

$x^2+y^2= z^2\to (x+y)^2-2xy=z^2$

$x^3+y^3=z^3\to (x+y)^3-3xy(x+y)=z^3$

from the second, using the first we get

$ z^2-2xy=z^2\to xy=0$

if $x=0$ then $y=z$

if $y=0$ then $x=z$

Therefore there are infinite solutions

$u(0,1,1);\;v(1,0,1)\forall u,v\in\mathbb{R}$.